# Can we use Java Spring mvc and Spring Boot at the same time in a project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jwt

Actually I want to implement JWT authentication in existing Spring based project. But all the examples and helping material i found, are in Spring Boot.
Kindly provide any relevant link which helps me in implementing JWT auth or guide me if we use Spring Boot together.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring boot is just a faster way of creating spring applications. Whatever works with Spring boot will work for Spring too. Spring is the superset of Spring boot. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

no you can't, 
here's an example spring security jwt with spring mvc
https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java?